# Why is the Connectionstring Empty when using Get-AzureRMStorageAccount?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-runbook, azure-rm

I've inherited a Powershell script that runs in an Azure RunBook.
In the script we need to read a StorageQueue. I'm having issues connecting to the StorageAccount.

The following snippet fails on New-AzureStorageContext, because the $connectionString  is Empty.

```bsh
$storageContext = (Get-AzureRMStorageAccount | Where { $_.StorageAccountName -eq $storageAccountName }).Context 
$connectionString = $storageContext.ConnectionString
$storageContextNew = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $connectionString
$queues = Get-AzureStorageQueue -Prefix $queueNamePrefix -Context $storageContextNew
```

How can I fix this so I have the ConnectionString and can connect to the Queue?

Comment: Turned out that our runbook was using some *very* outdated versions of packages, which I found out because some other packages where missing. Updating those packages fixed the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Try the command as below to get the `$context`, then use it to get the queues.

```
$SAResourceGroupName="<resource group name>"
$StorageAccountName="<storage account name>"
$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $SAResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName).Value[1]
$context=New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$queues = Get-AzureStorageQueue -Prefix testqueue -Context $context
```

[image]

Comment: This will not work in my situation, because I do not know the ResourceGroup. I have to search all storageaccounts for one with the correct name.